# What is the best way to deploy a create react app to Google cloud?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I don't want to use containers. Is it best to use Google app engine and deploy the static build from an express server like I have done before using Heroku. Or is there a better way ?

Comment: Check vercel.com. it hardly takes 20 seconds to deploy a site.

Comment: Are there any big companies using vercel ?

Comment: Check website. FYI It was ZEIT Now early. Now it is vercel.com. Secondly some big companies such as airbnb and github also use it.

Comment: Ill have a look , but just out of curiosity. What would the best way be to deploy a create react site to google cloud.